# Adding several special characters to existing regex

Tags: java, regex, validation

I use a regex pattern in a change password feature of my app. The requirements for the password are:

- at least 1 small letter
- at least 1 upper case letter
- minimum of 8 characters
- at least 1 number
- at least 1 special character

I want to add these characters to my pattern, but I couldn't seem to add the "\" and the single and double quotes. How do I escape them? I'm using Eclipse (Java) so escaping needs 2 backslashes

Right now, my pattern looks like this and it's giving me an error:

```
String customPattern = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])
(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\\-_+=/?.,>~\\\\|\\[];:\\"'{}])(?=[\\S]+$).{8,})";
```

Comment: look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html and here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not escape the `]` inside the character class `[!@#$%^&*()\\-_+=/?.,>~\\\\|\\[];:\\"'{}]` (right after `\\[`). Here is a working regex (with `^`/`$` anchors that will really enforce length check of the whole string if not used with `matches()`):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_+=\/?.,>~\\|\[\];:"'{}])(?=\S+$).{8,}$
                                                                ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB2nY6/1)

In Java, you can use it as

```
String customPattern = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\\-_+=/?.,>~\\\\|\\[\\];:\"'{}])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$";
```

Comment: If it was, please consider upvoting my answer. Actually, I was the first to let you know about escaoing `]` inside the character class, Avinash edited his answer quickly after seeing mine :)

Comment: @stribizhev totally wrong. I just added the wordings after your answer but take a look at my original regex, `]` inside the char class is escaped. I think you can't able to view that..

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Well, true, Avinash, I did not check the regex itself when you first posted it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Put a single backslash before double quotes and also escape `]` present inside the char class.

```
String customPattern = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\\-_+=/?.,>~\\\\|\\[\\];:\"'{}])(?=\\S+$).{8,}";
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I shall try that thank you. Are the four back slashes the correct way to include the "\" in my pattern?

Comment: yes, use four slashes to match a literal backslash character.

Comment: Thank you sir! I think it solved my problem. I'll test the pattern